# There is no package called 'stringi' when using library 'car'

Tags: r, namespaces, stringi

#### Purpose

I was trying to use `vif()` function from the `car` package of R.

#### Initial Error Messages

When I first executed `vif(X)`, an error message popped up as:

```
Error in vif(mod1) : could not find function "vif"
```

I tried `library(car)` and get a following error as:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘stringi’
```

#### References

I read and tried the following references until I solved the problem:

1. https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/issues/178

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

#### Step 1: Remove "stringi"

```
$ wget https://github.com/Rexamine/stringi/archive/master.zip
$ unzip master.zip
$ R CMD INSTALL stringi-master --preclean
```

#### Step 2: Reinstall "stringi" from binary (NOT source)

```
R$ install.packages('stringi')
```

You will be asked:

```
There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
        binary source needs_compilation
stringi  1.4.5  1.4.6              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel)
```

> Please answer **no** to install from binary.

#### Solved

Now try:

```
R$ library(car)
R$ ?vif
```

And everything works fine.